# Python - attempt at parallelising calculation inside class

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have the following working code:

```
from itertools import product
import time
import numpy as np

class Basis_NonI(object):
    ''' Non Interfering case'''

    def __init__(self, dimension, generation, embed_dimension = None):
        self.dimension = dimension
        self.generation = generation

    def KineticEnergy(self, vec):
        ''' Returns kinetic energy of a basis vector, according to formual 4*|M·b|^2'''
        return 4*np.abs(vec**2)

    def make_basis(self):
        t = time.time()
        x = np.arange(-self.generation, self.generation)  
        array = np.array([np.array(i) for i in product(x, repeat = self.dimension)]) #cube of basis states
        gens = np.abs(array).sum(axis=1)
        mask = np.where(gens<=self.generation)[0] #the product creates all elemnts up to maxg, but also some at higher maxg (maybe it's fine?)
        array = array[mask]
        gens = gens[mask]

        kins = np.array(map(self.KineticEnergy, array))
        uniqueK = np.unique(kins)

        group_gens = []
        kinenergy_gens = []

        for i in np.arange(self.generation):
            pos = np.where(gens==i)[0]
            group_gens.append(map(np.array, array[pos]))
            kinenergy_gens.append(map(np.array, kins[pos]))

        group_kin = []
        generation_kin = []

        for j in uniqueK:
            posK = np.where(kins==j)[0]
            group_kin.append(map(np.array, array[posK]))
            generation_kin.append(gens[posK])

        print('Basis took {} s'.format(time.time()-t))

        return group_gens, kinenergy_gens, group_kin, generation_kin, uniqueK

if __name__ == '__main__':

    b = Basis_NonI(1, 5)
    a = b.make_basis()
```

and I am trying to parallelise some of the calculations inside it so as to make it go faster (so that I can increase the size of the vectors involved).

`make_basis` has two `for` loops which fill two lists. So my first idea was to parallelise those two by spawning two processes:

```
from itertools import product
import time
import numpy as np
from functools import partial
from multiprocessing import Process

class Basis_NonI(object):
''' Non Interfering case'''

def __init__(self, dimension, generation, embed_dimension = None):
    self.dimension = dimension
    self.generation = generation

def KineticEnergy(self, vec):
    return 4*np.abs(vec**2)

def generation_basis(self, group_gens, kinenergy_gens, gens, kins, array):
    for i in np.arange(self.generation):
        pos = np.where(gens==i)[0]
        group_gens.append(map(np.array, array[pos]))
        kinenergy_gens.append(map(np.array, kins[pos]))
    return group_gens, kinenergy_gens

def kinetic_basis(self, uniqueK, kins, group_kin, generation_kin, gens, array):
    for j in uniqueK:
        posK = np.where(kins==j)[0]
        group_kin.append(map(np.array, array[posK]))
        generation_kin.append(gens[posK])
    return group_kin, generation_kin

def run(self):
    t = time.time()
    x = np.arange(-self.generation, self.generation)  
    array = np.array([np.array(i) for i in product(x, repeat = self.dimension)]) #cube of basis states
    gens = np.abs(array).sum(axis=1)
    mask = np.where(gens<=self.generation)[0] 
    array = array[mask]
    gens = gens[mask]
    kins = np.array(map(self.KineticEnergy, array))
    uniqueK = np.unique(kins)

    group_gens = []
    kinenergy_gens = []
    group_kin = []
    generation_kin = []

    func1 = partial(self.generation_basis, group_gens, kinenergy_gens, gens, kins, array)        
    func2 = partial(self.kinetic_basis, uniqueK, kins, group_kin, generation_kin, gens, array)

    p1 = Process(target = func1)
    p2 = Process(target = func2)
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()

    print('Basis took {} s'.format(time.time()-t))
    return group_gens, kinenergy_gens, group_kin, generation_kin, uniqueK

if __name__ == '__main__':

    b = Basis_NonI(1, 5)
    a = b.run()
```

But when I try to access `a`, it's a bunch of empty lists so it did not actually fill them.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to realize that each new process will get **copy** of the memory space (heap, stack etc.). Saying that, you need to pass the result of computation using some kind of IPC (Inter process communication) like [Queue](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue), [Pipe](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Pipe) or [Shared Memory](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes).

You can ease it by using [Pool](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) and [apply](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.apply) or [map](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map) which will do the IPC for you as shown in this example taken from docs:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(5) as p:
        print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))
```

Comment: what if I want to put it in a class method? Is it also going to work or is it less trivial?

Comment: Not sure if I understand. Class method as target for map or apply function should work as well.